# reading multiple cards/tags using smartcard.rb on ACR122U

Tags: ruby, smartcard

I am using the smartcard ruby gem to read nfc cards on an ACR122U nfc reader.

I understand the ACR122U can in principle read multiple tags, but it's by default using an "anti-collision" algorithm to only come back with one.

Any ideas how to read multiple cards in the reader using the smartcard gem?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a misunderstanding. You communicate always with one tag only, there is no possibility for a broadcast. Anticollision is the process, to select the the correct one of several tags in the field at the same time. Of course, after you are finished with one tag, you can deselect it and chose the next one to address.